# Including row at the bottom of Navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer from here:
[reference link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

I want to add "settings" and "exit" **at the end of the navigation list** but I can't.

Here is my code for drawer `activity_main.xml`:

`

```
<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`
```

I tried adding text to the end of the ListView and wrap them in RelativeLayout with aligning to the bottom. But no success so far.

This is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}
```

...

I just want to add another row at the end of the list in navigation drawer separated from the rest of the list. something like this:

[image]

Comment: i'm not 100% sure if you're trying to add elements to your listview, or add stuff after your listview.

Comment: I have my navigation drawer with list. But the list begins from the top to and ends at the bottom of the list. I want to add one row at the end of the list but separated from the rest of the list items.

Answer (score 3):

1. DrawLayout takes two children, one main display, the other the drawer, so you have wrap everything in two viewGroups.
2. The special attributes like gravity start need to be in the relative layout now, since it is now the direct child of DrawerLayout.

.....

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
          />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text = "button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button1" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text = "button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific to what's failing for you?

Answer (score 2):

I think You should add drawer list in linear layout. just like below

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/frame_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/ne"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/setting_background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_weight=".85"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/newslist_drawer"
    android:layout_weight=".15"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newslist_done"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="  setting"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newslist_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="  exit"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

For the people who is still looking for a complete answer. Here is a few points.
1) if you add a linearlayout or relativelayout as a container, don't forget marking the container layout as start - this is key to let drawerlayout treats the container as a sliding drawer, or you will receive an error.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_gravity="start"
>
```

2) declare a global variable for this container layout, get a reference to it in onCreate(), something like :

```
RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
public void onCreate(){

   mRelativeLayout = ..
}
```

3) there are at least 3 places you need to use the relativelayout.

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            mDrawerLayout.close(mRelativeLayout); 
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            mDrawerLayout.open(mRelativeLayout);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
```

The last one is the selectedItem method call
`mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mContainerLayout);`

Answer (score 1):

Late response! But i have just been working on something very similar that solves this issue without modifying the xml at all.

Each drawerlayout has a addHeader(View v) function and an addFooter(View v) function. They accept **inflated views** as their param.

```
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.comic_drawer_footer, null);
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_content);
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bookmark_list);
mDrawerList.addFooterView(footer);
```

Comment: If your listview is short, you will see the footer actually just floats in the middle of screen.

Comment: you can change the height of the drawer to match parent then and this should fix that problem.

Comment: If you post your issue in a question i will do my best to answer it. I can't help you with just a few comments of information.

Comment: These questions have been asked for quite a few times as I am searching with these topics. People are using linearlayout containing the listview and other widgets as the solution. My first try was to set the layout height. It won't work because this is a custom view. If you are curious about it, you can use the sample code of navigation drawer, and add a footer by using your approach. I make my comment to letting other people know the approach you suggested actually didn't work.

Comment: Unless you post your problem detailing your issue i'm not going to be able to help you. I would suggest you check your layouts and check implementation of the navigation drawer pattern.

Comment: I have figured it out. Thank you for your attention.